# Is it possible to run a python file from within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2012

I am completely new to Visual Studio and C#, so I apologize in advance if this sounds like a dumb question. I am trying to develop a Windows Forms Application such that when I click a button, a Python script is run, performing data analysis on some files, with the eventual goal of displaying that data as a graph on the Windows Forms Application after the button is clicked.

My question is: how do I get the python script to run when the button is clicked from the Windows Forms Application?

Comment: what have you tried.. have you executed a google search prior to coming here and asking how do I do something before doing any thing or showing any effort on your end? just curious

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You can create a process that runs python shell.

Pyton Tools for Visual Studio will help with debugging python from within VS

https://pytools.codeplex.com/

For more details and how to look at this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNNAOypc6Ek&hd=1

Comment: It wont work. Python tools is intended to create .net executables using the clr, not to invoke the python interpreter.

Comment: @oscar No, it isn't. Your getting confused with IronPython. PyTools is an IDE extension which lets you execute py files.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorry, you're rigth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible there is Microsoft approved extension for VS to yse  Python.
You can downloaded it from here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ea113de-a009-46cd-99f5-65ef0595f937

For more details and how to look at this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNNAOypc6Ek&hd=1